# Target definition file - Plugins downloaded location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have created the target definition file for our RCP application. This file contains remote location URL's for all plug-ins.

Some one can tell me where all these plug-ins will be downloaded on my local machine, while debugging my RCP application?

Comment: Is it here "Workspace-Location/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDE stores the plug-ins of the target platform in a *bundle pool* in the workspace. This bundle pool is located in `WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/`.